# How to transition Apple ID for iOS development to a different developer

Tags: ios, xcode4, iphone-developer-program

I am leaving my current position at the end of the week.  I'm a developer at a small-time shop, and my Apple ID is the only one attached to my soon-to-be ex-employer's Apple developer account.  We do have an app (although it's just one app) available in the iTunes app store.  So I went to the Apple developer portal and clicked on the "manage my Apple ID" where I changed the name attached to the apple ID.  This way, the person that still works here can manage the available app and I can move on to greener pastures.

So I changed the info, and it did change there, but in the Apple dev portal, it still seems to think that my name is the one attached to the apple ID.  I first thought that it might just be a separate process, but that was last Friday that I switched it over.  When I went to revoke my developer certificate and regenerate it for the new guy, it still has my name attached to the apple ID, even though the contact info is set-up to be the new person.

This is a real small potatoes shop, so I was trying to get their dev environment set up for whoever before I jet.

**Question:** How do I transition the Apple ID to the new person?  The new person isn't an iOS developer per se; he's the supervisor who (honestly) doesn't know a whole lot.  I appreciate any thoughts or advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple ID is tied to you (i.e. your name, your email address). You do not need to try and give ownership of this to someone else.  They should have registered and gotten their own Apple ID.  What you need to do is transition the Team Agent role to the new person.

It sounds like you were the one who signed up the company for the Apple developer program, and I would assume your account is the designated Team Agent.  This role should be transferred to the new person, and ultimately, you should be removed as a member of the team.

See here for details on how to transition the Agent role:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: Quick follow-up question: Does the new agent also have to pay the $99?  I added the guy as the team member, and when I go to transfer the agent role to him, all I get is a message that says "we cannot complete your request at this time."

Comment: The $99 should be for the company's enrollment in the developer program, not per team member.  So adding team members should not incur additional costs.